# HTML Replace Script only replacing first term

Tags: jquery, replace

I have this script running on a Japanese directory, working to replace English terms on the page for a Blog add-on for the terms that were not customizable. It works great but it only seems to replace the term the first time it sees it.

http://www.martyregan.com/jp/blog/

For example you'll see View Post, Tags, Feb are still in English on the bottom Blog Post.

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#pb_sidebar, #left-sidebar-inner, #pb_body, #main-content-inner, #sidebar-archives').each(function(i){
$(this).html($(this).html().replace('Category List','ブログテーマ一覧'));
$(this).html($(this).html().replace('Tag List','タグ'));
})
    })
```

How can I alter it so that it grabs the term everywhere it sees it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really battering the DOM with this approach, by the way.

Consider caching the .html() results, then running your replacements on that, first, before putting the new text back in the DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pb_sidebar, #left-sidebar-inner, #pb_body, #main-content-inner, #sidebar-archives').each(function(i){
        var mycontent = $(this).html();
        mycontent = mycontent.replace(/Category List/g,'ブログテーマ一覧');
        mycontent = mycontent.replace(/Tag List/g,'タグ');
        $(this).html(mycontent);
    })
})
```

Comment: You're right here, doing multiple updates to the DOM isn't the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: This a better way to do it?

Comment: It will certainly result in less DOM churn, which, depending on how much content you have, and how often you have to do this, could affect performance.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use regex with the `/g` option that will repeat otherwise `string.replace()` only runs once.

For example:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Category List/g,'ブログテーマ一覧'));
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, replace is a native JavaScript function. In order to let it replace every occurence, you'll have to use the g-Parameter for the RegEx you're searching for, example /searchstring/g instead of "searchstring"

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a global modifier to your replace:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Category List/g,'ブログテーマ一覧'));
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Tag List/g,'タグ'));
```